# to_timestamp() function in python giving null value in return

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a data set as follows in a CSV format

| ORDER_ID | ORDER_TIME |
| --- | --- |
| 8799 | 11/11/2008 01:34:16.564000 AM |
| 8854 | 4/18/2008 01:02:36.564000 AM |
| 8884 | 4/20/2008 10:38:44.886000 PM |
| 8899 | 12/16/2008 07:32:59.456000 AM |
| 8681 | 7/29/2008 08:59:06.250000 PM |

and we are reading the file with the following read function in python

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.read \
  .option("header",True) \
  .option("nullValue", "null") \
  .option("delimiter",",") \
  .option("multiLine",True) \
  .csv( csvfile, encoding="utf-8")

df = df.withColumn("ORDER_TIME", F.to_timestamp(F.unix_timestamp("ORDER_TIME", 'M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSSSSS a').cast('timestamp')))
```

When we run `df.show()` for the column ***ORDER_TIME*** we are getting `null` value
but I need it in standard spark format which is `2008-11-11 01:34:16`

The same command if I run it in **`pyspark`** terminal the output is proper for the same input.

All our packages are up to date and I have no idea about this issue.
Looking forward to the solution

Answer (score 0):

approach by using udf:

```
import datetime
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(8854, "11/11/2008 01:34:16.564000 AM"), (8799, "4/18/2008 01:02:36.564000 AM")], ("ORDER_ID", "ORDER_TIME"))

def standard_date_format(date):
  val = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f %p').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
  return val

fn1 = udf(standard_date_format)

df =df.withColumn('ORDER_TIME',fn1(col('ORDER_TIME')))
display(df)
```

[image]